# Confusion Regarding Escaping Special Characters in URL Parameters

Tags: ios, swift, url, escaping

**Background:**

I have read several questions answers here, but the more I read, it only gets more confusing.

**Task:**

I need to send a POST URL request with "trailing" parameters in the URI, like this:

`http://www.myhostname.com/functionName?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2`

Typically, I will create the parameter string with a format and insert the values for each parameter, like this:

```
let value1 = "Hello"
let value2 = "World"

let parameterString = "?parameter1=\(value1)&parameter2=\(value2)"

let requestURL = baseURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("\(fucntionName)\(parameterString)")
```

**Questions:**

1. Do I need to percent-escape the "**?**" before the first parameter?
2. Do I need to percent-escape the "**&**" before each subsequent parameter?
3. Do I need to percent-escape the "**=**" between each parameter name and its value?
4. Do I need to percent-escape the "**.**" if some parameter's value is a file name with an extension?
5. Should I escape using `URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet`, or do I need to define a custom character set?

---

**Update:**
If I escape using `NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet()` and `print()` the resulting string, the `?`, `=` and `&` remain intact. If I use that string to instantiate an `NSURL` and then print its `path` property (that is, a `String`), I get the same output.

But if I pass said `NSURL` instance as-is to `print()`, the ? alone gets percent-escaped (into `%3F`).

Comment: using `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters` with your `parameterString ` make sure your URL is percent escape correctly, i don't think u need to worry so much about that, just follow the URI format

Comment: Which allowed characters should I use?

Comment: `URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet ` is enough :D for some text searching situation i use normal `letterCharacterSet` though

Comment: OK, then I'm doing it right. Guess the 404 I'm getting is due to something else...

Comment: maybe your POST body? maybe those param need to be encode in the POST body instead of putting in URL? Or maybe your base URL? Try to print all of them may help u identify the problem...

Comment: No, the spec calls specifically for params in the URL, á la GET. The body uploads a file as described here: http://zcentric.com/2008/08/29/post-a-uiimage-to-the-web/ . Anyway, I'll try to figure it out talking to the server-side people, thanks. Feel free to post your comment as an answer.

Comment: cool :D hope u found the culprit, 404 error can be caused by many things in server side too, might be the API is not mapped with any service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create your String contain the URL first by combine Base URL with the param first and encode it using `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters` then only turns it to URL, the "**? & = . /**" should not be percent escaped in the URL

```
let escapedSearchText = searchText.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())!

let urlString = String(format:"%@/%@?parameter1=%@&parameter2=%@",hostName, functionName,value1, value2)
//http://www.myhostname.com/functionName?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2

let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
return url!
```